# How to override system activity in android for bluetooth (turn on BT and BT discoverable mode)

Tags: android, android-layout, bluetooth, android-dialog

This is bothering me for a long time: I have an App that has several dialog screens and activity screens. All in the same style of the App. There are only two situations in which I cannot override the UI style of the system, so that my App style doesn't look consistent in these situations. Don't get me wrong here: I DO NOT want to change the behavior of the system dialogs, I just want to apply my design style to it, so the App looks in all situations the same.
The situations in which I am forced to deal with the ugly system dialogs are when you want to request that Bluetooth is turned on, and when you want to set the Bluetooth adapter into discoverable mode.

There must be some way to override the layoutfile of the dialog so that I can apply my own App style to it (not changing any buttons, or text, just the UI style only).

Someone already tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think you can't do that.  Those dialogs might be influenced by the system theme that you have chosen for your app, but other then that you can't affect them.

I think it would be a security issue if you could - even just changing the styles would allow you to subvert the meaning of a system dialog.

Actually, I would say that the system dialogs should not be well integrated with your app - they should be the same style as the system and different then your app so that the user knows that they are system dialogs.

Comment: Too bad, this cannot be changed :(

Comment: The system dialog is terrible. When I have a long app name, it cuts the name and shows "LONG LONG LONG L... wants to turn on bluetooth"